# How do I select only a certain character of text and turn it into a break?

Tags: css, contains

I will have users input text in a textbox to set as their identifier, however, they can only enter 1 line of text. I have no way of changing that.

I would like to add CSS that takes the string of text and edits a `|` character and changes it to a `<br>`

The string of text they will type will be something like this: `1234-5678-1234 | Jim`

I want it to show up like this:

```
1234-5678-1234
           Jim
```

I'm guessing the code might look like this:

p:contains('|') {code for an enter and float right}

Comment: I believe you're looking for a masking function. It's not available through css. See http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Why would you do that? It would make what the user sees as his input different from what he actually enters. This sounds like poor usability: it is surprising and confusing.

Comment: If the user enters the text in a “textbox”, where only one line can be entered, this sounds like an `input` element. Why do you intend to style a `p` element then, and what would `<br>` help? (No markup works inside the value of an `input` element.)

Answer (score 0):

I would be posting this as comment but I need 50 rep :)

Just this:  What you are trying to do needs JS.  You should give RegExp a try.  There's not a way to do that using pure css.

Comment: Here's a link that shows how to use RegExp to replace the "|" symbol with a `<br>`: http://js.do/code/45489  Not sure about the `float:right` though.  I'm still searching . . .

Comment: I posted another answer that might have fixed your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to select an element on the basis of its textual content, except for the special case of empty content. There was once (in 2001) a [draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors) suggesting a `:contains(...)` selector, but this feature was removed as the draft progressed (to eventually become [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) recommendation).

Still less is there a way to select something *inside* an element based on its content.

Besides, adding `<br>` would not be possible. You cannot add tags or elements with CSS, only textual content via pseudo-elements.

Moreover, if the input is read in an `input` element, you cannot make its content displayed in two lines. If the user input is actually echoed an in different element, like `p` element, then it is programmatically copied there, so the question is why the change is made there. You can modify the content with JavaScript, and it would be rather simple to replace any `|` by `<br>` in the content of a `p` element.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try using `<div contenteditable="true"></div>`. You would be able to solve your issue, using JS by wrapping and adding tags as necessary. Also, textbox wont support multiline & formatting.

A good read for contenteditable attribute on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing and created the following RegExp:  [Example Here](http://js.do/code/45521)

```
<input type="text" id="demo" value="123-456-7890 | John Doe" size="35">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p style="text-align:left;" id="number"></p>
<p style="text-align:right;" id="name"></p>

<script>

function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").value;
    strnum = str.indexOf('|');
    var name = str.slice(strnum+1);
    var number = str.slice(0,strnum);
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
}
</script>
```

Is this what you want?